# Trying to rotate canvas, something is going wrong

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm trying to make a nice interactive map of my office in HTML5 for documentation purposes(tracking phone extensions, port numbers, etc), and since a lot of our offices and cubicles are the same, I figure I should have just one of each type of office, then just duplicate it for all of the offices it matches. My only issue is, I can't rotate the canvas properly. I've followed all the tutorials, but for some reason, my image keeps getting cut off. I can't seem to locate the source of the problem.

Any ideas?

Here is my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmcDw/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Test Interactive Office Schematic</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function addOffice(type, id, occupentName) { 

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.id = id;
            canvas.style.position = "absolute";
            canvas.style.left = "20px";
            canvas.style.class = "office";
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 0);
            if (type == 1) {
                canvas.width = 80;
                canvas.height = 80;
                context.lineTo(2, 0);
                context.lineTo(2, 20);
                context.quadraticCurveTo(22, 20, 22, 0);
                context.lineTo(60, 0);
                context.lineTo(60, 80);
                context.lineTo(0, 80);
                context.lineTo(0, 0);
            }
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();
            context.textBaseline = "Alphabetic";
            context.textAlign = "center";
            context.fillText(occupentName, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas = document.getElementById("1");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
            tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;
            tempCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.save();
            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.rotate(180 * Math.PI / 180);
            context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, 80, 80, 40, 40, 80, 80);
            context.restore();
        }
        addOffice(1, 1, "test");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: your fiddle is useless..format it...put the js code inside js section,bot the html

Comment: Better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KszcL/. The drawImage function is supposed to take an image as the first parameter, not a canvas object.

Comment: @Bucky24 [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()) can take any image element including `<img>`, `<canvas>`, and `<video>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you have translated and rotated the context you need to translate back:

```
context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
context.rotate(180 * Math.PI / 180);

/// here, translate back:
context.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
```

(you don't need to clip and/or specify width and height if destination size is the same as source size).

But if you simply want to flip the image or rotate it 180 you can instead use `scale` the canvas instead using a negative value - just remember to reverse the coordinates ([here's a demo of this technique](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/AXb2E/)):

```
context.scale(-1, -1);
context.drawImage(tempCanvas, -tempCanvas.width, -tempCanvas.height);
```

## More in-depth on transformation in general (update)

To better explain how transformations works lets go through the various stages.

`Origo` ([see definition here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/origo)) is always point [0, 0] in a coordinate system (or more accurately the point where the axis crosses). When you use transformations this is the point that gets translated in a context for a canvas.

This is also the reason why you manipulate the *context* an not the canvas directly as the transformations are applied to context and not the element (otherwise the element would be rotated itself when you applied a rotate transformation to it - which you can do by CSS).

Initially the coordinate system looks like this (white blended is non-visible areas of the canvas, the center square is canvas and the blue grid is the context and the current coordinate system):

(Note: ignore the negative Y axis - I somehow managed to overlook that detail when making the graphics - the y axis is of course positive vertically down).

[image: Inital]

If we now translate the canvas 3.5 by 3.5 points to get `origo` at center the context and coordinate system will now look like this:

[image: translated]

If we now wanted to apply rotation that will happen at the `origo` point. This is why we need to translate before rotate as when rotate is applied we get this result:

[image: rotated]

If we now just draw the image it will not be centered cause `drawImage` draws an image from the image's upper left corner. Which means it would look like this:

[image: drawImage non translated]

This is why we need to translate back `origo` so that we compensate for the image corner.

However, since we also have rotation applied the origo will be moved relative to the current systems orientation as well.

We translate back (half the size of the image to get the image's center point at the previous `origo` point) - the rotation remains the same:

[image: translated back]

Now we can call the `drawImage` as now you can see the `origo` seem to be in the correct position for this operation:

[image: final transform]

Comment: OOOOOHHH. So just to clarify, after I have rotated, the starting point for drawing stuff, gets reset to (0,0)? does this only hapen with Translate, or does it happen with other stuff?

Comment: @SalmonMode Actually nothing gets reset. As rotation happens around origo (0,0 point relative to coordinate system) you will need to translate before rotating to say "at this spot I want to rotate everything". But as `drawImage` draws the images from upper left corner at origo as well you will need to translate origo back so that the center of image now aligns with the previous center of rotation (not sure if that made more sense).

Comment: Ok, hold on. So lets say, I have my canvas. I translate "origo" to the center of it, in order to say"rotate from this point, instead of 0,0". Then once I rotate it, let's say 180 degrees, where is "origo" now?

Edit: On that note, is my coordinate system now flipped to where 0,0 is now on the bottom right instead of the top left?

Comment: @SalmonMode origio is always 0,0. What you are translating is the origo itself that always represents 0,0 in this context so when lets say translate origio 100 by 100 origo is still 0,0 but *relative* to the context upper left corner (not the canvas element) drawing anything at 0,0 will actually be drawn at 100,100. It can be hard to wrap ones head around this but see origo as the *"real"* canvas moving around inside the visible one. Every transform will happen at that origo point - or, origo represent 0,0 of the coordinate system where ever it may currently be relative to the visible canvas.

Comment: Aha! So in my scenario, I have to have origo(is that it's real name btw?) in the center in order to rotate it properly, otherwise, my canvas would end up to the upper left of where I started if I started from the top left of the canvas. And now I have to work with negative coordinates starting from the bottom right because origo is on the bottom right of my canvas. I'm not sure if I'm understanding it fully, but I at least have somewhere to go from. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SalmonMode thanks for the accept. I added a more in-depth explanation to transforms in my answer. origo is Latin for origin. Used in math for coordinates: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/origo

Answer (score 0):

The image won't show because you're drawing it outside of the canvas. Try this:

```
context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, 80, 80, -40, -40, 80, 80);
```